# Angular html5 mode to work with gh-pages hosting for SEO

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, seo, github-pages

I'm using Angular and Firebase for SPA. How do we get html5 mode to work with gh-pages so the dynamic bits of the site are crawled and indexed?

I've set html5 mode using $location and set the base url to '/'. Also included

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
```

in the index.html

This works but returns a cannot get /whatever when reloading the page it's on. Some posts point to rewriting the url on the web server but we can't do this with gh-pages.

Is there another way to make sure the site's dynamic content gets crawled? I don't care about pretty urls but the site's seo strategy includes adding articles so it would be a big hassle to make static pages just for the crawlers.

Site is at [Forging Technology](http://forgingtechnology.com)

Struggling with this last bit to complete the project. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Using the resolve property with a deferred promise in routing does the trick, except to get the firebase data $scope'd takes a 2000ms $timeout in the controller. Unfortunately, the $timeout makes google still crawl and index a page without data..